# node-inspector remote debugging cannot find server.js (ENOENT)

Tags: node.js, remote-debugging, node-inspector

I have a strange problem with **node-inspector**.

Trying to debug my nodejs app remotely ( `nodejs --debug` & ssh tunnel on 5858)

The app consists of a `server.js` main file and many other js files.

Node Inspector complains that it can't get server.js, however it's able to get the rest of files, and everything works 100%: file tree, profiler, console output, breakpoints (obviously elsewhere than in server.js) ...

The console shows the following error:

```
Page.getResourceContent failed.
Error: ENOENT, open '/opt/nodejs/fmetaserver/server.js'
```

The path is correct, the file does exist, and as you see below, the permissions of the file are exactly the same as those of the ones that work (all the rest in this dir, and under templates and node_modules)

```
drwxr-xr-x 6   99   99  4096 May 28 10:06 node_modules
-rwxr--r-- 1   99   99 16268 Jun  1 20:47 server.js
-rwxr--r-- 1   99   99   764 May 28 10:06 stringutils.js
-rwxr--r-- 1   99   99  8764 May 28 10:06 amazons3.js
drwxr-xr-x 3   99   99  4096 May 29 20:21 templates
```

What's going on?